# Snail Game using 2D dimensional data structure and loops

Tags: python

I'm trying to create this game where a snail "@" will move in the direction that you want it to within this box. When it moves to a space it leaves a trail behind. "_ ". I've coded it so that it can move right, but I'm not sure what to change so it can move down.

```
column = int(input("column"))

gameField = []

for i in range(row):
    gameField.append([])
    for j in range(column):
        gameField[i].append(" ")
 
def printField(listField):      
    for i in listField:
        for j in i:
            print(j, end= " ")
        print()
    
curRow = 0
curCol = 0

gameField[curRow][curCol] = "@"

game = True
while game:
    direction = input("wasdq")
    if direction == "q":
        game = False
    elif direction == "d":
        if curCol+1 == column:
            print("try again")
        else:
            gameField[curRow][curCol] = "_"
            curCol += 1
            gameField[curRow][curCol] = "@"
        printField(gameField)
        
    elif direction == "s":
        if curCol+1 == column:
            print("try again")
        else:
            gameField[curRow][curCol] = "_"
            curCol = curCol - 1
            gameField[curRow][curCol] = "@"
        printField(gameField)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters your user prompts aren't very clear. I would say something like

```
columns = int(input("Enter Columns: "))
```

And something similar for `wasdq` because I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with that.

But anyway, if changing the column moves your snail left and right, how do you move the snail up and down?

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
# This is a matrix that looks like
# [0, 1, 2]
# [3, 4, 5]
# [6, 7, 8]

zero = matrix[0][0]
one = matrix[0][1]
three = matrix[1][0]
four = matrix[1][1]
```

If your snail lived on the matrix, moving right would be equivalent from moving from cell 0 to cell 1 (as one example) and moving down would be equivalent to moving from cell 0 to cell 3 (as one example).